# GetAsyncKeyState() fails to return state of keyboard/mouse, while WM_KEYDOWN messages seem to work fine

Tags: windows, input, msdn

I'm writing a game where I use GetAsyncKeyState() for character control like WASD and mouse buttons, and the windows messaging system for menu stuff like text input and cursor control.

Every once in a while, my computer seems to get into this weird state where GetAsyncKeyState() doesn't return anything. It seems to be related to times when my game crashes. Once the computer is in this state, I don't know how to get it out unless I restart the computer.

The windows messaging system still works fine in this case- if I type the 'W' key, I still get a WM_KEYDOWN message and the letter can show in my menu system, but the following method, which normally works, will fail:

```
bool result = (GetAsyncKeyState(vkey) & 0x8000) != 0;
```

For all I know, this is being caused by an external program (such as Synergy+, which I use to share mouse/keyboard input between computers), however I haven't been able to prove this yet.

Whatever the cause, I don't want this problem to occur to an end user. Are there any techniques to diagnose and repair a state like this?

EDIT: Perhaps this is some kind of driver issue? I just noticed that when my computer gets in this state, my mouse no longer processes the shortcuts I've assigned to its extra buttons. I don't know enough about how all this works to know what to blame in a case like this.

Comment: This is not a common problem.  Something wrong with your machine, you'll have to figure it out by yourself.  Sure, start by ditching stuff like "synergy".

Comment: "GetAsyncKeyState() doesn't return anything" - do you mean the call GetAsyncKeyState does not return and your program is hung on that call?

Comment: @Hans I was afraid of that :)

Comment: @nanda Sorry, I mean that it always returns 0. It should return non-0 when the tested key is down.

Comment: I am having a similar problem... wondering if perhaps it has anything to do with there being no window opened as yet.

Comment: @Mike, I don't think that was my problem, as this would occur even during gameplay, when there was a window open for rendering. Haven't seen the problem in a while, and I haven't been using Synergy for a while either. Probably going to chalk it up to being some kind of interference!